# Pebble can't install app in any way - cloudpebble or command line

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I've enjoyed developing simple apps for my pebble watch, but since yesterday I cannot install any new ones on my phone (I do have spare slots on pebble).

I've tried installing old (working) apps via cloudpebble portal, but I get following:

- Saving
- Compiling
- Preparing to install app
- Installation rejected. Check your phone for details.
  (Phone message: There was an error trying to install the provided app.)

So I've tried installation through a command line:

```
$ pebble install --cloudpebble -vvvv
```

But this is the output:

> INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 209.118.208.39
>   DEBUG:pebble_tool.util.analytics:Queueing analytics data: {'platform': 'native_sdk', 'data': {}, 'event': 'invoke_command_install', 'identity': {'sdk_client_id': '93381446-f47e-4be5-bd4a-781af1f42c3a', 'user': u'55b8844a6638300025560100'}, 'sdk': {'project': {'sdk': u'3', 'is_watchface': True, 'type': 'native', 'uuid': '2737c550-fd8a-4e70-82be-1b887e5d7a4d', 'app_name': u'MoveInGrid'}, 'host': {'platform': 'Darwin-15.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'python_version': '2.7.10', 'is_vm': False}, 'version': u'3.8.2', 'tool_version': '4.0.1'}}
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0
>   INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): td.getpebble.com
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /td.pebble.sdk_events HTTP/1.1" 200 0
>   Waiting for phone to connect...
>   Connected.
>   DEBUG:libpebble2.communication:-> WatchVersion(command=None, data=WatchVersionRequest())
>   DEBUG:libpebble2.communication:-> 0001001000
>   DEBUG:libpebble2.communication:<- 00960010015509b4fb76322e392e31000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035343636346264000005015222545f76312e352e350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000316331363237350001050152e2f83256335233000000000051313536303535453030513604750648b4b026658a035509b4fb656e5f55530000015858585858585800
>   DEBUG:libpebble2.communication:<- WatchVersion(command=1, data=WatchVersionResponse(running=WatchFirmwareVersion(timestamp=1426699515, version_tag=v2.9.1, git_hash=54664bd, is_recovery=False, hardware_platform=5, metadata_version=1), recovery=WatchFirmwareVersion(timestamp=1377981535, version_tag=v1.5.5, git_hash=1c16275, is_recovery=True, hardware_platform=5, metadata_version=1), bootloader_timestamp=1390606386, board=V3R3, serial=Q156055E00Q6, bt_address=04750648b4b0, resource_crc=644188675, resource_timestamp=1426699515, language=en_US, language_version=1, capabilities=24866934413088856, is_unfaithful=None))
>   Installing app...
>   **App install failed.**
>   INFO:root:Spent 0.001597 seconds waiting for analytics.

I've tried several things to resolve this issue:

- creating new project from provided template;
- disconnecting the watch;
- watch factory reset;
- iOS pebble app reinstallation;
- creating and linking to a new cloudpebble account,

but still no luck installing any new apps or reinstalling old ones...

Any help would be *greatly appreciated* (or more tips on what else to try...).

PS: Apps load just fine in an emulator.
PS2: I can download and install apps from the store just fine [I found PixelMiner that way : )].
PS3: I do have a developer connection on and there is a valid IP shown on iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Morris on pebble forums. I was developing for SDK3, but still running older version of firmware on a pebble watch. After an update, deployment works again!

### Original response:

You are building with the latest SDK but your watch has not the latest firmware.

### You either have to upgrade your Pebble Classic to firmware V3.8.2 (see [Upgrade to SDK3](https://help.getpebble.com/customer/portal/articles/2256017)) or if you want to build for the old firmware you have to use SDK2 instead (see [SDK2](https://developer.getpebble.com/blog/2015/12/01/A-New-Pebble-Tool/))